# Blender won't display texture, even in UV editor, Using a PNG (screen shot included)

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I have this scene where I modeled a tank for Unity, it is two objects, a top and a body. I unwrapped them in blender, made textures in zbrush, Now I want to make sure the seams look alright in blender before I export to Unity. I bring in the texture. I select all the entire body model and all the points in the UV editor and the 3d viewport. I set the display to textured. Nothing happens. I try pin and nothing happens. I have been messing with this way too long. I think Blender is broken but I really hope I just missed something.

Here is a screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using Cycles you also need to add it as a texture node for it to appear in the 3D view:

[image]

When in textured view the last selected image texture node is displayed, when in material view an approximation of the material is displayed, with all textures mixed according to the node setup.